# My dlog_print calls do not appear in the log, other things do

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-native-app

I'm making a watchface for Tizen. Whenever I use `dlog_print` to debug something, nothing appears in the log window. However, other log entries (not mine) do appear, in vast quantities.

This is my first Tizen app, and I have no idea what to try.

Starting with the [initial template for a watchface](https://developer.tizen.org/development/training/native-application/getting-started/creating-your-first-tizen-wearable-native-watch-application), I've added the following code to the update_watch function:

```
update_watch(appdata_s *ad, watch_time_h watch_time, int ambient)
{
    char watch_text[TEXT_BUF_SIZE];
    int hour24, minute, second;

    if (watch_time == NULL)
        return;

    watch_time_get_hour24(watch_time, &hour24);
    watch_time_get_minute(watch_time, &minute);
    watch_time_get_second(watch_time, &second);
    if (!ambient) {
        snprintf(watch_text, TEXT_BUF_SIZE, "<align=center>Hello Watch<br/>%02d:%02d:%02d</align>",
            hour24, minute, second);
    } else {
        snprintf(watch_text, TEXT_BUF_SIZE, "<align=center>Hello Watch<br/>%02d:%02d</align>",
            hour24, minute);
    }

    // debugging dlog...
    int ret = dlog_print(DLOG_FATAL, "USR_TAG", "test dlog boooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo!!!");

    switch (ret) {
        case DLOG_ERROR_NONE:
        snprintf(watch_text, TEXT_BUF_SIZE, "<align=center>NO ERROR<br/><font_size=50>%02d:%02d</font_size></align>",
                hour24, minute);
        break;
        case DLOG_ERROR_NOT_PERMITTED:
            snprintf(watch_text, TEXT_BUF_SIZE, "<align=center>NOT PERMITTED<br/><font_size=50>%02d:%02d</font_size></align>",
                    hour24, minute);
            break;
        case DLOG_ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER:
            snprintf(watch_text, TEXT_BUF_SIZE, "<align=center>INVALID PARAMETER<br/><font_size=50>%02d:%02d</font_size></align>",
                    hour24, minute);
            break;
        default:
            snprintf(watch_text, TEXT_BUF_SIZE, "<align=center>ERROR: %d<br/>%s<br/><font_size=50>%02d:%02d</font_size></align>",
                    ret, get_error_message(ret), hour24, minute);
            break;
    }
    // end of debugging dlog

    elm_object_text_set(ad->label, watch_text);
}
```

I expect the entry "test dlog boooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo!!!" to appear in the log window in Tizen studio once every second. However, it doesn't. The function's return value is 64 as I can see in the label. Positive return values indicate success (the number of bytes written), so why isn't it showing up?

I've also tried different levels of log other than `DLOG_FATAL`, with identical results.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your log viewer is showing emulator's log while you are testing the app in a target.

This happens a lot. You can further ensure it by executing `$ dlogutil -t 10` at the sdb shells of both the emulator and the target. It happens a lot during development especially if you have multiple targets and emulators are attached.

If you are confused which machine you are using in the sdb shell, try `$ cat /etc/tizen-release`.